# Moving from macbook (without GPU) to linux system with Titan V, only getting a 4x speedup, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, gpu

I was prototyping a network architecture out on the macbook, and after finding something I was somewhat happy with, I wanted to test it out on a big data set on a system with a Titan V as the macbook was very slow for the bigger dataset (12 hours). I was expecting at least a 50x speed up per epoch over the CPU, if not more. Why might the speedup be only 4x (3 hours)?

Err it turned out to be some very tricky driver issues, and by just cleaning out my vm and starting over, was able to fix it.

This line of code in particular was invaluable - some of the other checks on "is tensorflow using the gpu" I found hovering around the web were not adequate to solving this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""A script for testing that TensorFlow is installed correctly on Windows.

The script will attempt to verify your TensorFlow installation, and print
suggestions for how to fix your installation.
"""

import ctypes
import imp
import sys

def main():
  try:
    import tensorflow as tf
    print("TensorFlow successfully installed.")
    if tf.test.is_built_with_cuda():
      print("The installed version of TensorFlow includes GPU support.")
    else:
      print("The installed version of TensorFlow does not include GPU support.")
    sys.exit(0)
  except ImportError:
    print("ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.")

  candidate_explanation = False

  python_version = sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor
  print("\n- Python version is %d.%d." % python_version)
  if not (python_version == (3, 5) or python_version == (3, 6)):
    candidate_explanation = True
    print("- The official distribution of TensorFlow for Windows requires "
          "Python version 3.5 or 3.6.")

  try:
    _, pathname, _ = imp.find_module("tensorflow")
    print("\n- TensorFlow is installed at: %s" % pathname)
  except ImportError:
    candidate_explanation = False
    print("""
- No module named TensorFlow is installed in this Python environment. You may
  install it using the command `pip install tensorflow`.""")

  try:
    msvcp140 = ctypes.WinDLL("msvcp140.dll")
  except OSError:
    candidate_explanation = True
    print("""
- Could not load 'msvcp140.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be
  installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment
  variable. You may install this DLL by downloading Microsoft Visual
  C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 from this URL:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587""")

  try:
    cudart64_80 = ctypes.WinDLL("cudart64_80.dll")
  except OSError:
    candidate_explanation = True
    print("""
- Could not load 'cudart64_80.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from
  this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit""")

  try:
    nvcuda = ctypes.WinDLL("nvcuda.dll")
  except OSError:
    candidate_explanation = True
    print("""
- Could not load 'nvcuda.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow requires that
  this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
  environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'.
  If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the
  correct driver installed.""")

  cudnn5_found = False
  try:
    cudnn5 = ctypes.WinDLL("cudnn64_5.dll")
    cudnn5_found = True
  except OSError:
    candidate_explanation = True
    print("""
- Could not load 'cudnn64_5.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a
  separate step from installing CUDA, and it is often found in a
  different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the
  necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 5.1 from this URL:
  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn""")

  cudnn6_found = False
  try:
    cudnn = ctypes.WinDLL("cudnn64_6.dll")
    cudnn6_found = True
  except OSError:
    candidate_explanation = True

  if not cudnn5_found or not cudnn6_found:
    print()
    if not cudnn5_found and not cudnn6_found:
      print("- Could not find cuDNN.")
    elif not cudnn5_found:
      print("- Could not find cuDNN 5.1.")
    else:
      print("- Could not find cuDNN 6.")
      print("""
  The GPU version of TensorFlow requires that the correct cuDNN DLL be installed
  in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Note that
  installing cuDNN is a separate step from installing CUDA, and it is often
  found in a different directory from the CUDA DLLs. The correct version of
  cuDNN depends on your version of TensorFlow:

  * TensorFlow 1.2.1 or earlier requires cuDNN 5.1. ('cudnn64_5.dll')
  * TensorFlow 1.3 or later requires cuDNN 6. ('cudnn64_6.dll')

  You may install the necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN from this URL:
  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn""")

  if not candidate_explanation:
    print("""
- All required DLLs appear to be present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues""")

  sys.exit(-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Copy paste, run this code. Will tell you if you have tensorflow GPU support.
For example, on my MacBook Pro it says

```
TensorFlow successfully installed.
The installed version of TensorFlow does not include GPU support.
```

Answer (score 0):

This Medium article goes into some surprising performance benchmarking between an M1 and a Titan.  M1 systems are very powerful.  https://medium.com/macoclock/apple-neural-engine-in-m1-soc-shows-incredible-performance-in-core-ml-prediction-918de9f2ad4c

Comment: Can you please provide a quick summary of what is described in the linked source? Many thanks!